# How to set color of Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Twitter Bootstrap 3.2.0 and I need to change the color of the "navbar" from basic black to another color.  I've tried everything and I can't get it to change in CSS.

I have gotten it to work properly in an add-in that calls a CDN yet I need to control it myself in CSS.

I have properly loaded the bootstrap files in the proper order.

Does anyone have a method that will let me change this - either with a style sheet or in-line command.

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: I'm sorry that someone felt the need to rate this question negatively. As it turns out there was a file with in my sample pages called bootstrap-theme.min.css which effectively negated all of my navbar settings even though it was placed  BEFORE my own navbar settings. When this was removed EVERYTHING worked!  Yes - I'm a newby - Just so future readers know, I had spent SEVEN hours on this before asking my question.

Comment: My research included many posts here on Stackoverflow, blog entries, sites specifically discussing BootStrap and numerous youtube videos.

I tried EVERYTHING and NOTHING worked thanks to the file used as an example on the getbootstrap.com site - bootstrap-theme.min.css!

Comment: I GREATLY appreciate the posts of the two folks who were willing to help and in the process I found the cause of the problem I was having!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the default navbar, it's as simple as to target the `.navbar-default` class, like this:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #FC0;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

And onbiously you can play with screen sizes, use different colors based on which page you are and so on

I made a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6mZ7N8cbyj) to show you

Comment: Thanks for the example code!  I was using the navbar-inverse class and it apparently it doesn't respond to the navbar-default CSS settings!

Answer (score 3):

Just go here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and customize the navbar then download the customized Boostrap.

Comment: Thank you VERY much - I will use this in the future once we decide on the colors!!!